# Method variable errors. Unknown reasons

Tags: c#, sql-server, variables, methods, scope

The following methods for getting the database name and password are fine as they are.

```
public static string getdbname(out string dbname)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the database name.\n");
    string dbasename = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    dbname = dbasename;
    return dbname; 
}

public static string getdbpass(out string dbpass)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the database password.\n");
    string dbasepass = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    dbpass = dbasepass;
    return dbpass;
}
```

When accessing the variables, I get an error saying `invalid expression term string` from getdbpass() and `expected }` from getdbname.

```
/**
 * Create string for an SQL Connection
 **/
public static string connTest()
{
    // Call in the out variables
    string name, pass;
    getdbname(out dbname);
    getdbpass(out dbpass);
    ...
    ...
```

I hope this helps you in figuring out what is wrong as I have tried several things ranging from renaming variables all the way to relocating the variables. None has worked yet.

Comment: Do you have that 'string' type name in the parenthesis or is that just a copy/paste error? If not, then that's the issue - it should be 'out'.

Comment: Which parenthesis? I'm trying to pass the variable dbname to name which name has to be declared first. @500-InternalServerError

Comment: You are likely putting the statements outside of a method body. You can say `string x;` outside a method body, and it means "declare a field called x". But you can't say `M(x);` outside a method body; that's a statement, not a field declaration.

Comment: OK, now with your update you are declaring variables with names `name` and `pass` and then passing non-existing variables with names `dbname` and `dbpass`.

Comment: Also, I note that a method which returns a value *both* directly and via an `out` parameter is bizarre. Why do you have an `out` parameter in the first place?

Comment: So confusing. I'm fairly new to C# but I had to learn it for my work. I had some help from work on the questions I asked and that was what I was guided to do. Don't ask why, I wouldn't know. @EricLippert

Comment: @DustinKoeller: I would ask for clarification from whomever told you to use an out parameter here, because that's a very strange thing to do.

Comment: What would you do? @EricLippert

Comment: @Dustin: you would do what I suggested in my answer.  Also go through some tutorials: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb798022  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string dbname;
string dbpass;

getdbname(out dbname);
getdbpass(out dbpass);
```

Your  methods both return *and* pass back using `out` the same value. You might want to reconsider that.

I would prefer just declaring as returning the value:

```
public static string getdbname() { ... }
```

and calling as:

```
string dbname = getdbname();
```

Try to avoid using `out` to return values from methods.

Comment: I tried that way and it entered the method first and then went to the calling to repeat the pattern.

Comment: Wish I could print screen it and it on here but the getbdname(out dbname) and getdbpass(out dbpass) are erroring. Big red line underneath. Let me update the code.

Comment: @MitchWheat: It doesn't *have* to work. The original poster is likely forgetting to put the method calls *inside a method body*.

Comment: Sorry, psychic powers bit rusty.

Comment: No. I'm putting it inside the method body.

Comment: @DustinKoeller: OK good. You reported an "expected }" error, which is highly symptomatic of putting stuff inside a class and outside a method body.

Comment: @MitchWheat For the record, I'm removing my answer, as far as I'm concerned, this is the right answer, the OP just doesn't follow instructions. You already got +1 from me.